# Chai-Http always returns 404 error code

Tags: node.js, express, chai-http

So basically, I have this rest api written off Node and Express using Typescript. I am trying to use chai, chai-http and mocha to get the api endpoints tested. But whichever test runs, I always get a 404 not found. Here is my code:

**app.ts:**

```
let mongodbURI;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
  mongodbURI = process.env.MONGODB_TEST_URI;
} else {
  mongodbURI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
}
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const mongodb = mongoose.connect(mongodbURI, { useMongoClient: true });    
mongodb
  .then(db => {
    setRoutes(app);
    if (!module.parent) {
      app.listen(app.get("port"), () => { });
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });

export { app };
```

**routes.ts:**

```
export default function setRoutes(app) {
    const router = express.Router();
    const userCtrl = new UserCtrl();
    router.post('/register', userCtrl.createUser);
    { .... }
    app.use('/api/v1', router);
}
```

**user.spec.ts:**

```
const should = chai.use(chaiHttp).should();
describe("Users", () => {
  it("should create new user", done => {
    const user = new User({
      name: "testuser",
      email: "testuser@example.com",
      mobile: "1234567890",
      password: "test1234"
    });
    chai
      .request(app)
      .post("/api/v1/register")
      .send(user)
      .end((err, res) => {
        res.should.have.status(200);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Not alone this but any route I try, I get a 404 error. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Hope it doesn't matter but I use mocha for running tests.

Comment: Your test setup correctly could you please share with us the error text you're facing in your terminal

Comment: Here is my complete log - https://pastebin.com/8dHK1YHZ

Comment: try to remove your `package-lock.json` and you may also need to reinstall your dependencies

Comment: i tried what you suggested but still the same log. 404s all around.

Comment: what is the complete log of `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-24T04_48_26_904Z-debug.log` file

Comment: this https://pastebin.com/T5HUqtNL

Comment: have you tried to use the `expect` function instead. this function had been used in the docs like so `expect(res).to.have.status(200);`

Comment: Let me try that but even then it shouldn't return a 404 not found right. It should return something else.

Comment: @AmrAly not working still...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as though you're establishing your routes asynchronously (they are only established after your mongodb instance has been connected). This is likely to be part of the problem, I'd recommend moving the `setRoutes(app)` part *outside* of the promise chain, and instead you can allow each route to `await` for the mongodb connection:

app.ts

```js
let mongodbURI;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
  mongodbURI = process.env.MONGODB_TEST_URI;
} else {
  mongodbURI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
}
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const mongodb = mongoose.connect(mongodbURI, { useMongoClient: true });    
mongodb
  .then(db => {
    if (!module.parent) {
      app.listen(app.get("port"), () => { });
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });

// setRoutes goes here, not inside a Promise 
setRoutes(app);
export { app };
```